# Lightning Web Security and postMessage

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, managed-package, iframe, postmessage

We are using **postMessage** to communicate a LWC with an iframe embedded in it.

The content of this iframe is in the same origin.
It's a static page loaded from a static resource.

When we activate Lightning Web Security on a String '22 org, this postMessage causes an "Illegal Invocation" exception.

The following code works perfectly when we deactivate Lightning Web Security and fails when we activate it.

```
this.template
    .querySelector('iframe.myIframe')
    .contentWindow.postMessage("a message", window.location.origin);
```

We have open a case in Salesforce because this is clearly a bug on the new version, but since this may take some time... **do you know of a workaround?**

The iframe contains an html with some custom JS libraries that do not work when imported directly on a LWC (this is why we are using the iframe instead of a normal LWC component).

We need the new Lightning Web Security option in order to use LWCs from a Managed package.

Comment: Is it throwing CORS errors?

Comment: Also, why wouldn't your JS libraries work when imported?  To me thats a red flag, and your workaround isn't working on the new version.  Could you fix your custom JS to work in LWC?

Comment: Yes, I have discarded any CORS related problem and try all the possible options in the second parameter of the postMessage.

About the custom JS, they are some minified third party libraries for map visualization and they are not meant to be changed. I have read in Salesforce forums that this libraries make some references to the window and that is why they cannot be imported on the LWC.

Comment: Have you tried binding it yet?  It seems its losing context.

Comment: What do you mean by binding it? I know about using bind to share context between functions or objects, but how would you do it between iframes?

Comment: I think static resource is loaded  with a domain from visualforce thus it is of different origin. Have you tried to use `*` instead of `window.location.origin`?

Comment: We opened a case in Salesforce and they fixed the bug after a few weeks.
Now the same code I posted in the question works fine.